# Using one variable given to change another variable given with methods

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm trying to, if stringNumber (randomized) is one, make num 1. If string number is two, make num two, etc. using a method. This is an example, and the real program will be on a much larger scale.

```
import java.util.Random;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int num;
      int num2;
      int num3;
      num = num2string(StringNumber);
      num2 = num2string(StringNumber);
      num3 = num2string(StringNumber);
      System.out.println((num + 10)); //should print out 11, 12, or 13
      System.out.println(num2);
      System.out.println(num3);
  }

  //Picks a number.
  public static String numPicker() {
      Random rgen = new Random();
      int rNumber;

          rNumber = rgen.nextInt(3) + 1;

      if (rNumber == 1)
          return "Number 1";
      else if (rNumber == 2) 
          return "Number 2";
      else if (rNumber == 3)
          return "Number 3";
      else
          return null; //Should never happen
  }

  private static int num2string() {
      //In this case x = One
      if (StringNumber.equals("Number 1"))
          return num as 1;
      else if (StringNumber.equals("Number 2"))
          return num as 2;
      else if (StringNumber.equals("Number 3"))
          return num as 3;
      else
          return null; //should never happen
  }
```

The correct version of this would do the following: 11, 12, or 13 should print out. Then 1, 2, or 3 should print out. Then 1, 2, or 3 should print out again.

Comment: num2string() should have a parameter as the input.

Comment: You should try to write some code before you ask the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I had to convert num to Strings, then parse it once I finished.

```
String StringNumber = RandomNumberGenerator();
String num;
num = num2string(StringNumber);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

Making variables to call to the method.

```
private static String num2string(String StringNumber) {

    if (StringNumber.equals("Number 1"))
        return "1";
    else if (StringNumber.equals("Number 2"))
        return "2";
    else if (StringNumber.equals("Number 3"))
        return "3";
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Integer.parseInt() method, which takes a string as an argument and retrieves int from it... 
Also, use equals() when comparing 2 strings.

Comment: In the real program I would change just words into certain numbers. Thanks though!